# Python reverse each word in a sentence without inbuilt function python while preserve order

Tags: python, string, list, split, reverse

**Not allowed to use "Split(),Reverse(),Join() or regexes"** or any other
helping inbuilt python function

input something like this:

```
"   my name   is scheven     "
```

output like this:

```
"ym eman si nevehcs"
```

you need to consider removing the starting,inbetween,ending spaces aswell in the input

I have tried 2 tries, both failed i will share my try to solve this and maby an idea to improve it

First try:

```
def reverseString(someString):
    
    #lenOfString = len(someString)-1
    
    emptyList = []
    
    for i in range(len(someString)):
        emptyList.append(someString[i])
    
    lenOfString = len(emptyList)-1 
    counter = 0
    while counter < lenOfString:
        if emptyList[counter] == " ":
            counter+=1
        if emptyList[lenOfString] == " ":
            lenOfString-=1
        else:
            swappedChar = emptyList[counter]
            emptyList[counter] = emptyList[lenOfString]
            emptyList[lenOfString] = swappedChar
            counter+=1
            lenOfString-=1
     
    str_contactantion = ""
    #emptyList = emptyList[::-1]
    #count_spaces_after_letter=0       
    for letter in emptyList:
        if letter != " ":
            str_contactantion+=letter
            #str_contactantion+=" "
        str_contactantion+=" " 
              
    return str_contactantion
```

second try:

```
def reverse(array, i, j):
    emptyList = []
    if (j == i ):
        return ""

    for k in range(i,j):
        emptyList.append(array[k])

    start = 0
    end = len(emptyList) -1
    if start > end: # ensure i <= j
        start, end =end, start
    while start < end:
        emptyList[start], emptyList[end] = emptyList[end], emptyList[start]
        start += 1
        end -= 1
    strconcat=""
    for selement in emptyList:
        strconcat+=selement

    return strconcat

def reverseStr(someStr):
    start=0
    end=0
    help=0
    strconcat = ""
    empty_list = []
    for i in range(len(someStr)):
        if(someStr[i] == " "):

            continue

        else:
            start = i
            j = start
            while someStr[j] != " ":
                j+=1
            end = j
            #if(reverse(someStr,start,end) != ""):
            empty_list.append(reverse(someStr,start,end))
            empty_list.append(" ")

            for selement in empty_list:
                strconcat += selement
            i = end + 1


    return strconcat

print(reverseStr("   my name   is scheven     "))
```

Comment: This is two separate problems. Parse the full string into words, then use a function to reverse the word. Write unit tests for the two tasks first. The trick to "don't use the library" is you DO use the library, get everything working, then write your own replacement for library functions. (You do not want to be debugging the whole program and your functions at the same time, because you won't know which one is at fault.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works without managing indices:

```
def reverseString(someString):
    result = crnt = ""
    for c in someString:
        if c != " ":    
            crnt = c + crnt    # build the reversed current token
        elif crnt:  # you only want to do anything for the first space of many
            if result:
                result += " "  # append a space first  
            result += crnt     # append the current token
            crnt = ""          # and reset it
    if crnt:
        result += " " + crnt
    return result

reverseString("   my name   is scheven     ")
# 'ym eman si nevehcs'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def reverseString(someString):
    result = ""
    word = ""
    for i in (someString + " "):
        if i == " ":
            if word:
                result = result + (result and " ") + word
                word = ""
        else:
            word = i + word
    return result
```

You can then call it like this:

```
reverseString("   my name   is scheven     ")
# Output: 'ym eman si nevehcs'
```

Comment: Now it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
string = "   my name   is scheven     "


def reverseString(someString):
    result = ''
    curr_word = ''
    for i in someString:
        if i == ' ':
            if curr_word:
                if result:
                    result = f'{result} {curr_word}'
                else:
                    result = f'{result}{curr_word}'
                curr_word = ''
        else:
            curr_word = f'{i}{curr_word}'

    return result

print(repr(reverseString(string)))
```

Output:

```
'ym eman si nevehcs'
```

---

**Note:** if you're allowed to use `list.append` method, I'd suggest using a `collections.deque` as it's more performant than appending to a list. But of course, in the end you'll need to join the list together, and you mentioned that you're not allowed to use `str.join`, so that certainly poses an issue.

Comment: I think you should use `somestring` instead of `string` inside `reverseString()`

Comment: oh yeah, good point.